# how do I get the source (sende)r element of a kendoui widget

Tags: kendo-ui

How does one get the caller (sender) of the kendoui datepicker widget?  Or any widget for that matter.

```
<input id="datepicker1" class="datepicker" value="10/10/2011" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    // ready
    $(".datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
        change: onchange
    });
});

function onchange(e) {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanb/zz48F/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sender is available as `this.element`. It will be a jQuery object:

```
$(function () {
    function onchange(e) {
        alert(this.element.prop("id"));
    }

    $(".datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
        change: onchange
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zz48F/3/

Comment: is there good documentation for all the properties of (this) in kendoui?

Comment: @Bryan The `this` keyword is a JS feature, not a KendoUI feature. KendoUI has extensive documentation, but the quickest way to see what variables are available in any given situation is to set a breakpoint and inspect them - which is exactly what I did for this answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew (this) was the JS feature but was unsure what was coming back in the change event from KendoUI... I looked at the documentation (http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datepicker#events) but could not find anything on the (e) of what is coming back.  Nice! on the javascript debugging breakpoint, i did't even think of that. Thanks again!

Comment: This saved my day.  I had Kendo UI components in a table, and had to know which row the component was located by parsing its unique id with row and column numbers embedded. Worked great!!!

Comment: Really really helpful . Thank you very much. I have spent lot of time and it finally it served my purpose

Comment: Glad to hear that an answer that's *so old* still serves people. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kendo button:

You can get the sender in the onclick event of the button using the following :

```
clickSelector(e) {

        alert("button " + e.sender.element.prop("id"));
    }
```

and you call clickSelector from the on click event of the button(s)

for example if you have the buttons:

```
<button id="btnStudentAccounts"  type="button" class="k-button">Student Accounts</button>
<button id="btnFaculty"  type="button" class="k-button">Faculty</button>
```

And the code:

```
  that = this;
  $("#btnStudentAccounts").kendoButton({
            enable: true,
            click: function (e) {
                that.clickSelector(e);
            }
        });


$("#btnFaculty").kendoButton({
        enable: true,
        click: function (e) {
               that.clickSelector(e);
            }
        });
```

if you click over btnFaculty you get:

button btnFaculty