# $(this) not working on Kendo file upload

Tags: jquery, file, kendo-ui, upload

I have kendo upload control in my kendo grid as one of the column.  please find below column :

```
$(".files").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: "/api/test/test/test",
        removeUrl: "/api/test/test/test",
        autoUpload: true
    },
    success: onSuccess,
             multiple:false,
             error: onError,
             showFileList: true,
             validation: {
                 allowedExtensions: [".pdf", ".xlsx", ".docx", ".rtf", ".tif",".txt"],MaxFileSize:5242880
             }
});
```

**Row template :**

```
 template: '<div class="small-12 attachment-wrapper columns"><div class="row"><div class="small-11 columns"><textarea placeholder="Enter notes and descriptions here for claims that have been closed"></textarea></div></div><div class="row"><div class="small-6 attachment columns"><div class="demo-section k-content"><input name="files" class="files" id="files" type="file" /><span class=success></span></div></div></div>'
```

I am trying to update the closest span with the result obtained from the successful file upload .

```
function onSuccess(e) {
    alert(e.response.FileName);

    $(this).closest('span .success').text(e.response.FileName);
}
```

**But i am unable to locate the span , it always says undefined . I think that $(this) is not working on kendo controls .
When i do the same way for the button , it does work . How to get the context of the upload control and closest span by using jquery** .

Please suggest on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the answer from the other post :**

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223836/how-do-i-get-the-source-sender-element-of-a-kendoui-widget)

```
this.element.context.closest('td')
```

Then we can get reference to the jquery object of the column from which we will be able to locate the span easily .

Hope this helps some on else

Answer (score 0):

In the event, "this" is not a reference to the DOM element of the Upload widget, it is a reference to the Upload widget/class itself.

Try

```
this.wrapper.closest(...)
```

instead.